# Keeping generic types when implementing in class

Tags: java, class, generics, interface

I've done a lot of searching through generic type questions and just haven't found anything that has helped me figure out what I am doing wrong here.  I have an interface as follows:

```
public interface SortAnalysis<E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
{
    public long analyzeSort(ArrayList<E> list);
}
```

Now, the next step is making a class that implements this interface.  This particular class is going to use an insertion sort and I need to keep the ArrayList type 'E' generic, so I tried all sorts of things and ended up with the following:

```
public class InsertionSort<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements SortAnalysis {

@Override
public long analyzeSort(ArrayList list) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that when I try to do this for the parameter

```
ArrayList<E> list
```

the compiler gripes at me about implementing a supertype method.

I would really appreciate any direction of help.
Thanks!

**I can't mark this as answered yet, but it is.  I think my problem had been that when I had

```
SortAnalysis<E>
```

I did not have the generic typing listed after the class name.**

Comment: In the second code snippet, it should be `SortAnalysis<E>` and `ArrayList<E>`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.  I thought for sure I had already tried that but it might have been before I added the <E extends....>> after InsertionSort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the type like `SortAnalysis<E>` in

```
public class InsertionSort<E extends Comparable<? super E>> 
        implements SortAnalysis<E> {
```

when you omit it you have a [raw-type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and not a generic version.

Comment: Thanks Elliott - As I had mentioned in an above comment that someone told me the same thing, I was sure I had tried that already and was baffled when it didn't work.  I'm wondering if I had been missing all the <E extends....>> after InsertionSort at the time.

Answer (score 3):

When declaring your `InsertionSort` class, you are implementing the raw form of the `SortAnalysis` class.  That means that `analyzeSort` isn't properly overriding `SortAnalysis` when you include `<E>` on the `list` parameter.

Supply a type parameter in the `implements` clause.

```
class InsertionSort<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
    implements SortAnalysis<E> {
//                         ^^^
```

Now you can include `<E>` in the `list` parameter.